# React error when trying to get data from api using useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a simple weather web app using an api which contains an input form to search the city and the information to display. And I want to set the default city to a specific city using the useEffect hook. So, as soon as users open the app, the information regarding the city's weather will be displayed. However, it returns an error that says something like the data doesn't exist.

This is my App.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Search from './components/Search.js'
import './App.scss';

function App() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('London')
  const [unit, setUnit] = useState('metric')
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({})

  const key = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY
  const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}&units=${unit}`

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(api)
      .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok){
          throw Error('could not fetch the data')
        } 
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        setInfo(data)
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }, [city])  


  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Search setCity={setCity}/> 

      <h1 className='city'>{city}</h1>
      <h2 className='temperature'>Temperature: {info.main.temp}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Search.js file

```
import React from 'react'

function Search({setCity}) {

  const search = (e) => {
    const loc = e.target.value.trim().replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && loc !== ''){
      setCity(loc)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='search-container'>
      <input type="text" onKeyPress={search} defaultValue='London'/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

Error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')
```

It seems like the error happened because I tried to access the temperature information (info.main.temp) inside the h2 tag. But, if I remove it everything would work normally, and the info would still be retrieved form the api.

Answer (score 0):

You've initialized `info` to be an empty object -

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({})
```

The first time your component renders, there's no `main` property on the `info` object (since it's empty), so this call will always fail with the error you're seeing:

```
<h2 className='temperature'>Temperature: {info.main.temp}</h2>
```

To fix it, you could check to see if the property is there before you access it using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
<h2 className='temperature'>Temperature: {info.main?.temp}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect depends on "city". In the beginning, you are trying to show the temperature value before any city changes.

To solve this you can avoid trying to show  tag:

```
{info && <h2 className='temperature'>Temperature: {info.main.temp}</h2>}
```

or:

```
{info ? <h2 className='temperature'>Temperature: {info.main.temp}</h2> : <Loading/>}
```

in this situation, you do not need to set a default value to "info" useState.

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check that `info.main` is not undefined and then render it out, that will be better

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Search from './components/Search.js'
import './App.scss';

function App() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('London')
  const [unit, setUnit] = useState('metric')
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({})

  const key = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY
  const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}&units=${unit}`

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(api)
      .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok){
          throw Error('could not fetch the data')
        } 
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        setInfo(data)
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  }, [city])  


  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Search setCity={setCity}/> 

      <h1 className='city'>{city}</h1>
      {info.main ? (
        <h2 className='temperature'>Temperature: {info.main.temp}</h2>
      ) : (
        <h2 className='loading'>Loading...</h2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an interface for weather API like below.

```
export interface Coord {
  lon: number;
  lat: number;
}

export interface Weather {
  id: number;
  main: string;
  description: string;
  icon: string;
}

export interface Main {
  temp: number;
  feels_like: number;
  temp_min: number;
  temp_max: number;
  pressure: number;
  humidity: number;
}

export interface Wind {
  speed: number;
  deg: number;
}

export interface Clouds {
  all: number;
}

export interface Sys {
  type: number;
  id: number;
  message: number;
  country: string;
  sunrise: number;
  sunset: number;
}

export interface RootObject {
  coord: Coord;
  weather: Weather[];
  base: string;
  main: Main;
  visibility: number;
  wind: Wind;
  clouds: Clouds;
  dt: number;
  sys: Sys;
  timezone: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  cod: number;
}

export interface IWeather {
  coord: Coord;
  weather: Weather;
  base: string;
  main: Main;
  visibility: number;
  wind: Wind;
  clouds: Clouds;
  dt: number;
  sys: Sys;
  timezone: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  cod: number;
}
```

Then in App.tsx you need to modify 2 things.

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState<IWeather | null>();
```

and

```
<h2 className="temperature">Temperature: {info?.main?.temp}</h2>
```

you can check [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-current-weather-demo-xfznyv)

let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: `useState<IWeather | null>()` should be `useState<IWeather | undefined>()` since you're not providing an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that error just because you are trying to access temp data before getting data from api

just add null check "?" after info whenever try to access data from info and it will check for temp data once get data from api

and declare info state as null while declaring

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState(null)



<h2 className='temperature'>Temperature: {info?.main.temp}</h2>
```